# Sending data packets over udp

Tags: udp

I am creating an app that acts as a remote control for a lighting console and I need to send commands to the console over UDP. The protocol that I am using has its own custom header. How do I create the data packet with header and message to send over UDP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test the protocol, without writing any code, I suggest you use [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The probably most powerful solution you can use is [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), which is a python module that allows very advanced packet crafting and manipulation. See its documentation or search the interwebs for examples to find out how to generate arbitrary packets and transmit them.

If you can't use python for some reason, there are multiple command line tools for packet generation, one other example being nping ([documentation](http://nmap.org/book/nping-man.html)), the brother of nmap, the popular network scanner. nping has options to generate UDP packets with arbitrary payloads, with can be specified as a hex string, for example.

There may be other options as well. It would be good to know more details like the operating system you're on or where you get your input data from, and in which format.